# how to extract facebook post number from the url?

Tags: php, facebook, url, facebook-php-sdk

I'm making an application, where I need to use the post number of the post

I want the user to paste the url like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sameple_page/posts/674053579296790?stream_ref=1
https://www.facebook.com/thinkdigit/photos/a.304388242384.154049.110963532384/10152000893017385/?type=1&theater
```

I'm unable to extract the post number from these URLs

Comment: I don't know why did you decided to choose the hard, you could call `/feed` and get the id fairly easy

Comment: You should definitely follow @AdamAzad's advice and not do this for a couple of reasons. First, your app will only be able to see the post if it's public, so it'll break very easily. Second, these IDs are transient and there is no guarantee they will still be of the same format, type, or structure (and certainly not the exact same ID) at any point after originall seen. Thirdly, any info you do grab this way is "scraping" and [not allowed](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php). [Use the Graph API instead](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first URL you could use:

```
$origPath = "https://www.facebook.com/sameple_page/posts/674053579296790?stream_ref=1";
$pos1 = strripos($origPath, "/");
$pos1++;
$pos2 = strripos($origPath, "?");
$len = $pos2 - $pos1;
$newPath = substr($origPath, $pos1, $len);
echo $newPath;
```